# Unreal Engine crash with AddDynamic

Tags: c++, constructor, delegates, unreal-engine4

I have a problem with binding OnAudioFinished delegate.

Searched for some time but haven't find good answer yet. I've followed this  [answer](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/534021/how-to-use-the-onaudiofinished-event-in-c.html)!

My code compiles without any error at all, however when my project is loading it crashes with this errors:

```
UE4Editor_!TBaseDynamicMulticastDelegate<FWeakObjectPtr,void>::__Internal_AddDynamic<UAudioController>() [d:\path\delegates\delegatesignatureimpl.inl:1140]
UE4Editor_Project!UAudioController::UAudioController() [d:\path\private\audiocontroller.cpp:17]
UE4Editor_Project!InternalConstructor<UAudioController>()
```

What I do understand is that constructor crushes my engine, but i don't know why is that happening. Here is my code that is responsible for this binding.

.h

```
static UAudioComponent* AudioComponent;

public:
    UAudioController();


void SoundFinished();
```

.cpp

```
UAudioController::UAudioController()
{
    AudioComponent->OnAudioFinished.AddDynamic(this, &UAudioController::SoundFinished);

}

void UAudioController::SoundFinished()
{
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 15.0f, FColor::Red, TEXT("Audio Finished trigger"));
}
```

Comment: Your debugger will be your best friend for issues like this. That said, my guess is that AudioComponent is not yet initialized when you call AddDynamic.

Comment: Also make sure your `SoundFinished` function is UFUNCTION.

Comment: Plase check my edited answer. using `NewObject<...>()` (as you mentioned in comment below) is definitelly not a correct way to work with components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UE, properties are not properly initialized during constructor run. They are when `PostInitProperties` is called (after load from CDO).

Also you should ask yourself if static class is necessary. If You need Singleton, you can store this in **GameInstance**. It is safer, especially in UE environment (you can't have static UPROPERTY() field etc.)

I believe that binding this event during `BeginPlay` should be sufficient. Removing is  good practice, although not necesarry when using *Dynamic* binding

```
// AudioController.h
virtual void BeginPlay() override;
virtual void EndPlay(const EEndPlayReason::Type EndPlayReasonType) override;

// AudioController.cpp
void UAudioController::BeginPlay() {
    Super::BeginPlay();
     AudioComponent->OnAudioFinished.AddDynamic(this, &UAudioController::SoundFinished);
}

void UAudioController::EndPlay(const EEndPlayReason::Type EndPlayReasonType) {
     AudioComponent->OnAudioFinished.RemoveDynamic(this, &UAudioController::SoundFinished);  
    Super::EndPlay(EndPlayReasonType);
}
```

**EDIT:** Since you named your class with *Controller* suffix, I suppose that this will be single occurence of this actor in level. So you don't need to have static pointer (it could get destroyed - again, this is UE speciality), just simply have *AudioComponent* as a **public** member in your controller:

```
// AudioController.h
UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "My Audio Conmponent", meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    UAudioComponent* AudioComponent;
```

and then correctly initialize it in constructor:

```
UAudioController::UAudioController()
    : Super()
{
    AudioComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UAudioComponent>(TEXT("MyAudioComponent"));
}
```

or

```
UAudioController::UAudioController(const class FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer)
    : Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
    AudioComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UAudioComponent>(TEXT("MyAudioComponent"));
}
```

Your component will be properly created and binded function will be executed as expected.

Also, as @JKovalsky mentioned, your `SoundFinished` method must be marked with `UFUNCTION()` macro when using *Dynamic* delegates.

Comment: I'm going to test it now and give you feedback how it goes! :3 Thank you for so big response.

Comment: Virtual functions you provided doesn't seem to work. They generate following errors:
`class "UObject" has no member "BeginPlay"
member function with 'override' does not override a base class member.`

i was searching for solution which led me to including Actor.h, however it changed nothing.


Without them, i compiled with no problem, however i still don't get this SoundFinished to fire even with bind in constructor.

My base class is inheriting form UObject

Comment: @AdrianRozlach what is base object for `UAudioController`? I supposed that it is `AActor`, but is seems like it is inherited directly from `UObject`... If it is the latter, is there any reason for that?

Comment: There is not. I'm pretty new to UE4, so i've chosen UObject for testing. I've changed base object to AActor and everything compiles just fine. Also my SoundFinished is `UFUNCTION()` , but still cannot get output from my function. After Sound is finished nothing happens at all.

I'm playing it from another function like this:
`UAudioComponent* AAudioController::SoundPlaying()
{
 if (AudioComponent)
 {
  AudioComponent->Play();
  return AudioComponent;

 }

 return 0;
}`
I get print in blueprint that it has finished with node isPlaying but no print from my SoundFinished

Comment: @AdrianRozlach are you familiar with concept of events and delegates? Here it is exactly the same. You call function named lets say `PlayMySound`. The implementation is like `AudioComponent->PlaySound(...)` and it immediatelly returns execution to a caller of that function. When *AudioComponent* has *SoundFinished* event bind, after currently playing cue ends it asynchronously call handler of that delegate, in your case `void UAudioController::SoundFinished()`. Everything you need to do after the sound is finished, you define it there.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Thank you kindly for patience and help :D

Comment: @AdrianRozlach You are welcome, I'm glad I see another game developer using EPIC Unreal Engine instead of that kid's toy Unity.     (Please don't let the flame war begin :D )